# Meaning of "ホーケー" in a sentence

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm reading some R-rated doujinshi on the internet and came across this line:

この立派なホーケーチOチンで!

I don't understand what "ホーケー" means. My guess is that it means something "take a look at this!" type of meaning, but I can't seem to find anything about this line.

As a whole, the sentence means something along the lines of "using this fine **** right here!".

Thanks!

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%85%E8%8C%8E Maybe?

Comment: @Ringil That's most definitely what it means.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes a lot of sense! I didn't know the original word, so I wouldn't have recognized the slang for it either. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It denotes [包茎](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8C%85%E8%8C%8E-131892), a condition where the foreskin of an adult male individual covers the tip of the glans.

In Japanese, the word 包茎 is used to refer to both 真性包茎 or phimosis, a condition where the prepuce is difficult or impossible to pull back past the glans, as well as 仮性包茎, a benign feature where it is simply long but easily retractable.

I assume katakana was used here for a more vulgar or humorous effect.